# Why/How CentOS use out-of-date kernel on a up-to-date release?

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

I noticed CentOS 6.9 is still using Linux kernel 2.6 which is already discontinued, but CentOS 6 is in active maintenance and it even have a kernel update days ago, which is also 2.6.x. Does CentOS modify the kernel to "backport" the bug-fixes to the old kernel? Or since CentOS is a free clone of Redhat, does this job actually done by Redhat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RedHat chooses stability over function. The kernel isn't the only ancient piece of software you'll find. Last time I used a RHEL server, most software on it was about 5 years older that the RedHat release itself. Check your bash and coreutils versions. On my Ubuntu 16.04 (about one year old):

- bash: 4.3.48
- find: 4.7.8
- grep: 2.25
- python v2: 2.7.12
- python v3: 3.5.2

Of course they backport security fixes.